# Save connected Socket in Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, asp.net-core, tcp

I'm trying to save a connected socket in a dictionary so my API doesn't have to create a new connection every time. My problem is that the socket gets disposed.
So when I call GetConnection() a second time socket.connected is false and socket.Available.Message is "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.".

```
public static class ModbusSocket
{
    private static Dictionary<IPAddress, Socket> socketList;


    public static Socket GetConnection(string server, int port)
    {

        if (socketList is null)
        {
            socketList = new Dictionary<IPAddress, Socket>();
        }
        IPAddress iPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(server);

        if (socketList.ContainsKey(iPAddress))
        {
            var socket = socketList[iPAddress];
            if (socket.Connected)
            {
                return socket;
            }
            else
            {
                socketList.Remove(iPAddress);                    
                socket = new Socket(iPAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(iPAddress, port);
                socket.Connect(ipe);
                socketList.Add(iPAddress, socket);
                return socket;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(iPAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(iPAddress, port);
            socket.Connect(ipe);
            socketList.Add(iPAddress, socket);
            return socket;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is some place else.  The connection is getting closed either from client or server.   You also have an error in code.  You cannot have two items in dictionary with same IP. Change following :from :  socketList.Add(iPAddress, socket); To : socketList[IPAddress] = socket.

Comment: Yes I have seen this and I remove the value now from the dictionary before I add it again.

Answer (score 1):

OMG I found the issue...
I invoked it with using:

```
        using (Socket s = ModbusSocket.GetConnection(hostIp, port))
        {
            var telegram = new Telegram();
            telegram.Set(0, AddressConst.PositionWindow, 4);
            var response = telegram.SendAndReceive(s);
            var result = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { response.Byte19, response.Byte20, response.Byte21, response.Byte22 }, 0);
            return result;
        }
```